# How do i increase an integer overtime? even when my application is terminated

Tags: xcode, time, int

I want to have a value that increase overtime even when the application is running in the background, but i do not want to use a server. Any ideas?

Comment: Your question title and body are different. How is "terminated" related to "running in the background"? And what is "overtime"?

Comment: "overtime" -> "over time".  As in, they want a scheduled task.

Comment: Ah. I was thinking it might be "overtime" meaning "after the program would normally have ended", like in a hockey game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can record the time the application started in a variable, and calculate that integer as a multiple of that number.

Comment: I'd second this, you can get the timestamp when the application starts and when it 'returns to the foreground' and use the difference to find your integer.